# msysgit commit encoding

Tags: version-control, github, msysgit

I am using msysgit on windows vista. I am still very new to it and on my first committed code to github another member said that all the tabs were replaced with spaces. Could it be possible that msysgit is changing this? I am editing the files in VS2008. Is is just come c sharp .cs files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely that msysgit replaced the tabs with spaces, that was more likely your editor settings.

You should configure your editor in such a way that you follow the established conventions of the project you're working with.

However, unless the file in question was a `Makefile`, my opinion is your editor settings are correct. :)

Comment: You're correct I found the options under Tools-> Options->Text Editor -> C# -> Tabs -> Insert Spaces/ Keep Tabs